# Multiple Instance of Embedded attribute in hibernate without overrided name

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, jpa, fluent-nhibernate

In Fluent N-Hibernate + N-Hibernate when you create and use component classes you do not need to explicitly specify a name for each one of the members in the user classes. The system by default or by some kind of convention create columns with following format.

```
[member name.particular component element name]
```

I wonder whether is there any such strategy exist when the JPA + Hibernate is used, so that you don't have to explicitly specify each column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Naming convention exist for Hibernate I place this config in my persistence.xml file and every thing went as I wanted.

```
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"
                  value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy"/>
```